# Python creating a new column row by row: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with a column whose values range from 0 to 100. Based on this column, I want to calculate a coefficient -> A

This coefficient is taken from 4 other variables: the values "b", "c" and "d".

A=c-((values-d)/b)

To calculate "b", "c" and "d" I do the following, where "x" is the column of values

```
def b(x):
    return 2.33 if x<=56 else 2.25 if 56<x & x<=111 else 4.6 if 111<x & x<=222 else 17.76 if 222<x & x<=667 else 668

def c(x):
    return 100 if x<=56 else 75 if 56<x & x<=111 else 50 if 111<x & x<=222 else 25 if 222<x & x<=667 else 0

def d(x):
    return 0 if x<=56 else 57 if 56<x & x<=111 else 112 if 111<x & x<=222 else 223 if 222<x & x<=667 else 668
```

A being the following

```
def a(x):
    return 0 if tvoc>667 else (c(x)-((x-d(x))/b(x)))
```

As I want to do this calculation on each row of my dataframe I run a lambda function

```
df["A"] = df.apply(lambda x: a(x[values]), axis=1)
```

but i have the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'

Anyone know how can i resolve this?

Comment: `return 2.33 if x<=56 else 2.25 if 56<x & x<=111 else 4.6 if 111<x & x<=222 else 17.76 if 222<x & x<=667 else 668`: you may want to split that across multiple lines and across multiple statements. This instantly becomes horrible to read and understand.

Comment: There is no need to wtite your `b`, `c` and `d` functions in one line. Try to expand the body of those functions and maybe you'll find the solution of your error.

Comment: `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float': because `&` means binary-and in Python. Use `and` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **and** instead of **&**...

From [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/):

"**and** is a Logical AND that returns True if both the operands are true whereas **‘&’** is a bitwise operator in Python that acts on bits and performs bit by bit operation."